# How to fit image to screen size in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am working on the image viewing part of an application and I am looking for a way to resize an image or fit it to screen. My setup currently looks like this.

```
photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Photo *pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
[pic setName:@"Picture"];
[pic setFilename:@"Pic.jpeg"];
[pic setNotes:@"Description"];
[photos addObject:pic];

pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
[pic setName:@"Picture2"];
[pic setFilename:@"pic2.jpeg"];
[pic setNotes:@"Description2"];
[photos addObject:pic];

pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
[pic setName:@"Picture3"];
[pic setFilename:@"Pic3.jpeg"];
[pic setNotes:@"Description3"];
[photos addObject:pic];

pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
[pic setName:@"Picture4"];
[pic setFilename:@"Pic4.jpeg"];
[pic setNotes:@"Description4"];
[photos addObject:pic];
```

And here is my prepare for segue method

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowPhoto"]) 
    {
        DisplayViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Photo *c = [photos objectAtIndex:path.row];
        [dvc setCurrentPhoto:c];
    }
}
```

What code should be added so that the images will fit to screen?

Comment: Use an imageview the size of the screen?

Comment: I mean make it so that a photo with a resolution larger than the Iphone screen will be letterboxed so that the entire image appears.

Comment: Then you want an image view the size of the screen, with the `contentMode` set to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your UIImageView is a subClass of UIView. This allows you to set the UIViewContentMode property. Your options here are:

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```

I believe you are looking for ScaleAspectFit.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIImageView which is the size of the screen. I am assuming all of your photos aren't the right ratio to not be stretched, so what I would do is have aforementioned UIImageView (from now on I'll call it `backImageView`) and set it's background to white, or whatever color is the background of your images.  Then in your viewDidLoad of your view, create a new UIImageView that is as big as possible while respecting the original aspect ratio, then put it on top of the new UIImageView.  Something like this:

```
double x = pic.size.width;
double y = pic.size.height;
if(x != 0 && y != 0){

    double ratio = x/y;
    CGRect cellImageFrame = backImageView.frame;
    UIImageView *actualPic = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    if(y <= 320){
            if(x < 320){

                y = 320;
                x = y*ratio;
                double xoffset = cellImageFrame.size.width -x;
                cellImageFrame = CGRectMake(cellImageFrame.origin.x + (xoffset/2), cellImageFrame.origin.y+2, x, y);
            }else{
                x = 320;
                y = x/ratio;
                double yoffset = cellImageFrame.size.height -y;
                cellImageFrame = CGRectMake(cellImageFrame.origin.x+2, cellImageFrame.origin.y + (yoffset/2), x, y);

            }
        }else{
            y = 320;
            x = ratio*y;
            if(x < 320){
                double xoffset = cellImageFrame.size.width -x;
                cellImageFrame = CGRectMake(cellImageFrame.origin.x + (xoffset/2), cellImageFrame.origin.y+2, x, y);
            }else{
                x = 320;
                y = x/ratio;

                double yoffset = cellImageFrame.size.height -y;
                cellImageFrame = CGRectMake(cellImageFrame.origin.x+2, cellImageFrame.origin.y + (yoffset/2), x, y);

            }
        }

        actualPic.image = pic;
        actualPic.frame = cellImageFrame;
```

This may require some tweaking, my code wasn't for the full screen, I tried to modify it but I can't test it right now so I can't be sure. Basically You just figure out the dimensions and aspect ratio, then find out if it's bigger than the screen. If it is, find out if it's wider than it's taller, or if it's square, and scale accordingly.  This doesn't account for scaling the images up, if you want to do that, run a check for a minimum size and then ramp it up using the aspect ratio.  Once you set the frame to the desired size, setting the image will make the image automatically fill the frame, as long as you have UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.